# Problems with https request when app is compiled for release & tips how to improve code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've recently discovered flutter. 
Built this as an app to learn [from here](https://github.com/Portocala/puffysticks-mobile-portfolio/tree/master/). It's basically a portofolio/gallery app.
I have a problem when the app is compiled for release (apk not on play store) it fails to load my http request I believe. In debug mode it all works well, but when compiled for release it fails and I don't know what is going wrong.
Also I'd like any advice on how to improve my code & optimise it (Images loaded from the http request are not compressed I know... it's not even an API yet, just outputting a json file).

Comment: Hi, please post whatever code that is causing your problems, it helps us debug the issue and provide you with more useful answers.

Comment: Hi, there is a github link to the code in there. I don't really know where is the problem as in debug mode it all works perfectly. I assume it has something to do with the http request as it stays with the initial body of the articles which is just a placeholder until there is a json response.

Comment: Suggestions for improving the code are too broad to handle on StackOverflow. If you have specific questions, feel free to add those separately as new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter requires the INTERNET permission on Android for development purposes (hot reload, hot restart, breakpoints, ...). So it adds that by automatically on debug builds, you can check this in the file located at `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`.

[See this template file from Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app/android.tmpl/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl#L3-L6):

```xml
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

On release builds this doesn't get added automatically so you need to add it to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `android/app/src/main/` folder yourself.

Comment: This, did indeed solved my problem, it's even mentioned here https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest, but I must've skipped it by mistake.